# Twitter iOS Flow

Tags: ios, ios5, twitter, twitter-oauth

My app does automatic tweeting and I'm wondering if this flow is allowable.

The user clicks on a twitter connect button on one of my pages, then it directs them to the login page in settings. After they've logged in, i'd send an automated tweet to their page.

Is this legal to do? Only asking if this is legally ok to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as legality goes, I would imagine this is fine if they **know** that the app will tweet for them.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter has a page telling developers about these sorts of things.
https://dev.twitter.com/terms/api-terms

See Section II, subsection 1, part B.